# VBA Excel: Feasible combination creator using single list of elements with no element repeating

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Sample Screenshot of Excel Sheet]

I have the following Excel sheet which has random number combinations build using numbers from 2 to 50  in set of 3, 2 and 1 in Column A. 
I am trying to build whole possible combinations between Column A elements such that the obtained combination doesn't have any repeating numbers in them and contains all the number from 2 to 50. 
My current code starts from A2 and builds only a single combination set. It doesn't evaluate other possible combinations with starting element as in A2, it then goes to A3 and then builds only one combination set using A3. This step continues for A4,A5...

This is my current code.

```
  Private Sub RP()

    Dim lRowCount As Long
    Dim temp As String, s As String
    Dim arrLength As Long
    Dim hasElement As Boolean
    Dim plans() As String, currentPlan() As String
    Dim locationCount As Long
    Dim currentRoutes As String
    Dim line As Long

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    lRowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    locationCount = -1
    line = 2

    Debug.Print ("*********")

    For K = 2 To lRowCount - 1
        currentRoutes = ""
        For i = K To lRowCount
            s = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)
            Do
                temp = s
                s = Replace(s, " ", "")
            Loop Until temp = s
            currentPlan = Split(Trim(s), ",")
            arrLength = UBound(currentPlan) - LBound(currentPlan) + 1
            hasElement = False

            If Len(Join(plans)) > 0 Then
                For j = 0 To arrLength - 1
                    pos = Application.Match(currentPlan(j), plans, False)

                    If Not IsError(pos) Then
                        hasElement = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
            If Not hasElement Then
                currentRoutes = currentRoutes & (Join(currentPlan, ",")) & " "
                If Len(Join(plans)) > 0 Then
                    plans = Split(Join(plans, ",") & "," & Join(currentPlan, ","), ",")
                Else
                    plans = currentPlan
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    If locationCount < 0 Then
        locationCount = UBound(plans) - LBound(plans) + 1
    End If

    If (UBound(plans) - LBound(plans) + 1) < locationCount Then
        Debug.Print ("Invalid selection")
    Else
        Debug.Print (Trim(currentRoutes))
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(line, 11) = currentRoutes
        line = line + 1
    End If

    Erase plans
    Debug.Print ("*********")
    Next K


End Sub
```

Comment: Well, but what is your question? You cannot throw in your code and wait for us to fix it. If you expect help on an issue you should ask a question that we can answer.

Comment: My question is, if we start to build combinations set with starting element as A2, it only finds a single combination set,i.e, it cant evaluate for all other possible set starting with A2.
Here it first selects and check from A3 if it has similar element and update it to the current plan if there is none. Likewise it builds the combination set. But what if we start from A2 and doesn't select we might have a different combination set right. How to take care of this problem. Sorry I am new to this and hope I am clear..

Comment: Are you aware of that 12 number sets already have `479001600` different permutations and 17 sets already `3.5568742809e+14` permutations? You won't be able to calculate that in a short time.

Comment: Your concern is correct. But the time is not a constraint right now. I am only worried about the code which is not working as I hoped to work :(

Comment: To find permutations you will need a recursive method ([like shown here](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/generating_permutations)). But more then 7 numbers/sets will kill your Excel already. So what you want is just not possible in Excel.